# Equivalence of singular matrix properties (2)

Tags: linear-algebra

So another implication I can't manage to prove is the following:

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix,

**I**) $A\vec{v}=\vec{w}$ for some $\vec{v}\neq\vec{w}$

**II**) $A$ has no inverse.

To show: $I \Rightarrow II$.

I have no clue on how to use **I**...

Comment: The implication is not true. Consider, e.g. $A=2I$ and $v\ne0$ over the real field.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it was a $2\times2$ matrix. Does that change anything...?

Comment: No, it doesn't. For $A = 2I$, you get $Av = 2v \ne v$ whenever $v \ne 0$, regardless of the dimension.

Comment: Any matrix multiplied by a vector must give just another vector, and not generally the same vector. Your statement would have been right if $w$ is a 0-vector and $v$ is a non-zero vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, the statement is incorrect. However, I suspect a typo, or a similar small mistake, and I want to offer two possible corrections similar to your original statement (and each other).

1. As Abishanka Saha wrote in comments, one correct version of this is

   $$v \ne 0,\ Av = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \text{$A$ has no inverse}.$$

   You can prove this by assuming the opposite (i.e., that $A$ has an inverse $A^{-1}$) and noticing that

   $$0 = A^{-1} \cdot 0 = A^{-1} A v = v,$$

   which is a contradiction with the assumption that $v \ne 0$.
2. Another possible correction of the above statement is this:

   $$v \ne w,\ Av = Aw \quad \Rightarrow \quad \text{$A$ has no inverse}.$$

   You can easily prove this by noticing that this is equivalent to

   $$v \ne w,\ A(v - w) = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \text{$A$ has no inverse},$$

   which is the same as the correction 1, for a vector $v - w \ne 0$.